# PHP date function error

Tags: php

I need to get year 30+ years in the future, which is why I am using below code.

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
$dateOneYearAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +30 year");
$endYr = date('Y', $dateOneYearAdded);
```

But as I tested this code its working for 26 years only. I can add only 26 year into the current year. If I try to add more than 26 then it will revert to the year 1970.

Below code is working fine:

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
$dateOneYearAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +26 year");
$endYr = date('Y', $dateOneYearAdded);
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is it an error in the PHP function?

Comment: You need to use the datetime object if you want to go past the 2030s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations, you have encountered the [Y2K38 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). You will either need to switch to a 64bit system, or use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which can represent (virtually) arbitrary dates.

Answer (score 3):

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) for information.

The UNIX timestamp counts the number of seconds since 1970, and as a 32-bit integer it has a maximum range of 2038.

You should use a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) object instead.

And of course, if you are storing dates in a database, be sure to use a DATE or DATETIME field.

Answer (score 1):

It's the timestamp you're asking for is greater than the maximum integer value that PHP can hold on your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is so because

> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0
>   this range was limited from 01-01-1970
>   to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g.
>   Windows).

you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP - [date() function changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php),

> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0
>   this range was limited from 01-01-1970
>   to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g.
>   Windows).

So be sure to check the [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Upgrading PHP won't help if you're still on a 32 bit system - DateTime is the right solution.